# Nova Python Client - List available IP addresses

Tags: python, openstack-nova

I have been using:

```
nova.floating_ips.list()
```

to retrieve all known floating IP addresses within my OpenStack deployment, is there a known way to retrieve only the available IP addresses?  That is I don't want IP addresses that have already been assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `floating_ips.list()` method returns a list of floating ips, where each address has the following attributes:

- `fixed_ip`
- `id`
- `instance_id`
- `ip`
- `pool`

If you filter the list of address with `instance_id is None`, you'll get a list of floating ips that are not currently in use:

```
unused_ips = [addr for addr in nova.floating_ips.list() if addr.instance_id is None]
```